# How to keep the same style for a table using openpyxl and python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

So my goal was to add data in an already existing table using openpyxl and python. I did it by using `.cell(row, column).value` method.

After doing this I had a problem because the table I was writing the data in was not expanding correctly. So i found this method and it worked fine :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#getting the max number of row
ok = bs_sheet.max_row

#expanding the table
bs_sheet.tables['Table1'].ref = "A1:H"+str(ok)
```

What I initially thought is that the format of the table would expand accordingly. What I mean by that is if I had a formula in a column, when expanding using openpyxl it would also expand the formula (or the position etc.). Just like it works when you do it manually. But it doesn't. And this is where I have a problem because I haven't found anything.

What I am having trouble with is when extending the table, the shaping that was already done on the existing rows doesn't extend down on the rows of the table. Is there a way I could fix this ?

Comment: This query explains how to extend the range of table correctly. Which I have already managed to do. What I am having trouble with is when extending the table, the shaping that was already done on the existing rows doesn't extend down on the rows of the table.

Comment: 'shaping'? Do you mean 'shading'? Are you talking about 'Table Styles' under the 'Design' Tab? Are you saying if you add another row of data under the last row of the table the new row does not take on the table style of the rest of the table?

Comment: Yes, let's say my first row I have my values centered in their cell. If I add a new row of data, the table will extend but the values will not be centered. But if I extend manually the table, it will automaticly center the values and formulas if I have some.

Comment: Ok, I believe I see the issue. I think this is probably to be expected due to the way openpyxl works. The text justification being duplicated if you manually add the row is probably an Excel function (like word suggest) but Openpyxl does not use Excel. The new rows will pick up a Table Style since that's applied to the whole table which you extend to the new rows. If you could set text justification in a Table Style that might have sorted it for you but seems there is no text justification option there. How are you setting text center justify in the table presently?

Comment: I am setting it by choosing the option in the alignement section on the home tab.

Comment: Since Openpyxl does not use Excel, maybe Xlwings does and will let me do what I need to do ?

Comment: OK, I'd have expected you would have to apply justification the same way so if you were doing that programatically you'd need to run the same code after adding the new row(s). **However** I can confirm if you add additional rows using Xlwings the Table will expand to the new rows and they will have the same justification as previous rows in the Table.

Comment: OK then I will use Xlwings to solve my problem. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using xlwings helps to keep the same format (including justifications, formulas) of a table.

When inserting data, the table will automatically expand. See example below :

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book('test_book.xlsx')

tableau = wb.sheets[0].tables[0]
sheet = wb.sheets[0]

tableau.name = 'new'
sheet.range(3,1).value = 'VAMONOS'

wb.save('test_book.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

In ths example, it will add value in an alreading existing table (and also change the name of the table). You will see the table already expanded when opening the file again.